# Create a simple POP3 *SERVER*

Tags: .net, sockets, pop3

There are tons of Google examples on making a POP3 client in .net but I want to make a simple custom POP3 service/server to retrieve email for the user from a custom database.  Are there any components or examples of that?

Comment: Thanks for those things so far.  I must add this would be my first step into the world of sockets and services.  One of the problems I am having is not knowing how the sockets remain open, listening, multiple users at the same time?

Comment: Researching a bit more, should I be using a socket service or a remoting?  I have done neither before.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an [open source .NET POP3 server](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/ENG/Products/Mail_Server/mail_index_eng.aspx?type=info). And since you mentioned you're new to sockets programming, here's a [tutorial for that](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/), too.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this mock smtp server](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/fakesmtpservice) a long time ago.  You can use that code to start with and some "real logic" to it.

Comment: Additionally, this RFC should be good for reference: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc821.txt

Answer (score 0):

There's a Delphi example [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-a-POP3-Server/) which might get you started. It shouldn't be too hard to pull out the basic parts of the POP3 spec and write to those, either - relevant information [here](http://www.kewl.lu/articles/pop3) for Telnet commands.

As well, an [RFC here](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1725/index.htm) describing the protocol in more detail.